# How do you sculpt a texture into a 3D Model (i.e. stencil overlay)

Tags: modeling

How do you sculpt a texture into a 3D Model? Such as using a stencil in 3dCoat as shown below

[image]

Comment: Probably this could help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YNxmh5UVi08

Comment: No, I tried to make this clear. I am not looking to texture a 3d model. I am looking to take a texture and literally sculpt out cracks etc into the geometry using the texture as a stencil

Comment: Set the texture mapping to Stencil in the brush settings

Comment: answer: https://imgur.com/6OM7STb

Answer (score 3):

- Load your texture in *Properties* panel > *Texture*.

[image]

- Switch your 3D view to *Sculpt* mode.
- On the left (tools panel), choose the *Draw* brush.
- Open the <kbd>N</kbd> panel on the right of your 3D view and click on the *Tool* tab. Open your texture so that the brush will use it, choose *Mapping > Stencil*.

[image]

- The texture should be displayed on the bottom left corner of your 3D view, it might be very transparent for the moment. In the same panel as before, under Display, increase the *Texture Alpha* if necessary. Enable *Dyntopo* if your object is not high poly enough and choose the adequate *Detail Size*, or give your object a *Multiresolution* modifier.

[image]

- Move your texture in the 3D view: RMB to move, <kbd>Shift</kbd> RMB to scale, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> RMB to rotate. Paint on your object.

[image]